# change the mime-type of particular static files in tornado web

Tags: python, tornado

i have a bunch of files in my /static/ dir serverside with names like:

```
Slide0.html    Slide121.html  Slide143.html  Slide165.html  Slide187.html  Slide208.html  
Slide28.html   Slide4.html   Slide71.html  Slide93.html
Slide100.html  Slide122.html  Slide144.html  Slide166.html  Slide188.html  Slide209.html
```

and i fetch them on the same domain and insert them to a iframe periodically, all they do is to render some images, but the browser is giving the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/static/Slide66.html".
```

i tried to subclass the staticfilehandler in vain:

```
class StaticHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):

def get(self, path):
    abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.root, path))
    mime_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(abspath)
    if mime_type:
        self.set_header("Content-Type", mime_type)

    if 'Slide' in abspath:
        self.set_header('Content-Type',"image/jpg" )
```

but the error persists how do i adjust it?

Comment: what version of tornado are you using?  also, maybe don't call set_header("Content-Type") twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Tornado 3.1 you can subclass `StaticFileHandler` and override `get_content_type()`.

```py
class StaticJSONFileHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):
    def get_content_type(self):
        return 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your browser is fetching "Slide66.html" to use as an image. You are likely generating HTML that has an "img" tag using "Slide66.html" as the "src" attribute.

Tornado is doing the right thing. If "Slide66.html" is truly an image then it should be "Slide66.jpg". If it is truly html then it can't be the "src" of an image.